# Paging and PIC executables

Tags: x86, operating-system, x86-64, virtual-memory, position-independent-code

I'm having a hard time understanding the need for PIC executables when virtual memory is being used. From what I gathered each program is assigned an entry in the page table and therefore has the illusion that it has the whole memory at its disposal while the paging mechanism takes care of possible relocations, pagefaults and so on.So if any program has the illusion of owning all  possible memory addresses why would one use a PIC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't *need* it, and until the last year or two, all Linux executables were position-*dependent* (not PIC).  See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux).

You can still build non-PIE executable with `gcc -fno-pie -no-pie`, and static ELF executables are always non-PIE with their load address chosen at link time.  Typically defaulting to putting the start of the text segment at `401000`.

Position-independent ELF executables started out as a hack: an ELF shared object with an entry point.  But these days that's widely used and the `gcc` default on most Linux distros.  The load address can be randomized at runtime.

---

Also note that many OSes support runtime fixups when loading an executable or library at something other than its preferred address.

ELF shared objects on Linux for example can contain relocations for 64-bit absolute addresses, so you *can* have traditional jump tables (array of code pointers) or statically-initialized arrays of pointers (to data or functions) in code compiled with `gcc -fPIC` for x86 and x86-64.

---

Note that `gcc -fPIC` also enables support for symbol-interposition, so functions can't directly access global variables; they have to load the address from the GOT, unless the symbol has "hidden" ELF visibility.  (Or of course if you make it `static` instead of global).

See https://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/

(Some of the ideas proposed in that blog have been implemented, for example GCC supports `-fno-plt`.)

The actual cost of just position-independence with `-fpie` is pretty small.  But still non-zero on OSes where position-dependent executables are guaranteed to load in the low 32 bits of virtual address space (e.g. Linux), so you can take advantage of 32-bit absolute addresses for 5-byte `mov r32, imm32` instead of 7-byte RIP-relative LEA to put a static address into a register, or `[array + reg]` to index a static array with its address in a `disp32` displacement as part of an addressing mode..

Answer (score 3):

Two major reasons:

1. Shared libraries. Libraries can't be guaranteed to load at a specific address -- even on a 64-bit system, there's no way to guarantee that every library will have a unique load address which won't collide with any other libraries, or with dynamic memory allocations. As such, code in shared libraries is compiled as PIC so that it can be loaded at any address that it's needed at.
2. Security. Having specific code present at predictable locations in memory is a security risk, as it enables [exploits which jump to short code "gadgets" in memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming) which can be strung together to perform arbitrary operations. [Relocating code randomly at 
   application startup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) helps defeat these attacks.